# Allow Lambda execution only by another Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I've got the following problem:
I've written a Lambda function which should not be called by an API Gateway, Kinesis Firehose Transformation and so on.

The only way how this Lambda should be called is by another Lambda function.

How can i restrict this access?

Best regards

Answer (score 4):

It isn't really a matter of "restricting access", it's really a matter of "not allowing" access in the first place.

By default, all users, functions etc have **no permissions**. For a user or service to call a Lambda function, it must be explicitly given that permission. **So... don't give anything that permission!**

"But," you say, "I'm granting `lambda:invoke` on `Resource: *` to all my users!"

Well, that's not a very good idea, then!

If that's the case, it might be easiest to have the Lambda function check how it was invoked and exit if it is not how you want it to be called.

Alternatively, you'll have to change how you grant `invoke` permission to your users and services.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I've got an question to that line: "If that's the case, it might be easiest to have the Lambda function check how it was invoked and exit if it is not how you want it to be called."
How do I do that? The context object doesn't give me information about the caller does it?

Comment: It doesn't look like there is a guaranteed method to discover the calling entity. See: [How to know event souce of lambda function in itself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41837288/174777)

Comment: @Johnny90 the alternative to John's link would be that you somehow make sure that the function payload contains the information you need to identify the caller, e.g. you could sign the function payload with a secret and verify it. However, I'd rather go his originally suggested way by only giving permissions to those resources which should be able to call the Lambda function. That's the reason why these permissions exist.